# Is it good to use globals() in Python?

Tags: python, constants, global

My code includes a constants.py module that needs to initialize two capitalized constant variables with two functions, and may I wonder if it is good to:

(1) initialize the variables as None and then
(2) use globals() in a main() function to set the variables' values?

Thank you.

Comment: Why can you not simply do `CAPVAR = function` ? Why do you need to use `globals` for that ? Or, if you don't need to, why would you want to ?

Comment: No, it is not good to use `globals()`.  Also, these by definition aren't constants if you're changing them at runtime.

Comment: Thank you all! It turned out that I do not need to use globals after looking at the program's structure, as @Programmer said.

Comment: And @Samwise your explanation on constants inspired a lot and thanks!